# How to consume data provided by silverlight class library in a web page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, class-library

How to consume data provided by silverlight class library in a web page ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear.

Best I can suggest is to implement a Portable Class Library - such libraries can be used both by Silverlight as well as regular .NET applications.